# Is there any way in python to know all installed application with version in my system (Windows & Linux both)?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, windows

i wanna make a script that will tell all installed application on system it can be Linux and windows both. anybody got any lead about it? need help!

Comment: about windows I remember reading [link](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/03/finding-installed-software-using-python/ ) this articlve where they did it

Comment: Are you trying to reproduce Windows' "Add and remove programs" feature? What about, let's say notepad? Do you consider this being an installed application? (It simply a *.exe in the System32 directory)

Comment: @Dominique no it's not like that I'm trying to find out a solution and this application listing is just a part of it and not only on windows it will be on Linux also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Windows, but with Linux you could:

- get the installed packages list from the package manager, but it would not find applications installed outside the package manager
- get the list of `*.desktop` files installed. This would get all applications which have a desktop icon. It would however still not guarantee that you have *everything*. I would suggest reading the [Desktop Entry Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) for more information.